# Парсинг последней записи на стене vk

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api, javascript

О новом посте вконтакте нужно узнать самому первому. Чтобы не сидеть за компом целый день, решено использовать `vk api`. При помощи метода `wall.get` получить запись - не проблема. Но неужели это все дело нужно зациклить, чтобы метод вызывался каждую секунду?

Подскажите, может, есть какое-то более элегантное решение, которое, например, оповестит меня само о новом посте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Upd.** Посты в группах придётся поллить раз в секунду. Push уведомления только для чатов и заявок в друзья.

---

Можете сделать приложение, которое будет слушать push-уведомления от ВК.

См. метод [`account.registerDevice()`](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=account.registerDevice):

> Подписывает устройство на базе iOS или Android на получение Push-уведомлений.

Answer (score 0):

Каждую секунду? Товарищ, я в шоке. Можно, конечно, бросить куда-нибудь скрипт, который будет тянуть посты, а от клиента уже обращаться к обработчику, который скажет, есть пост или нет.

А с циклом всё равно рано или поздно какая-нибудь дрянь случится.

Comment: > Каждую секунду?

Добро пожаловать в мир, где автоматизация стоит на службе у человека, а не наоборот. Анонимный доступ к апи разрешает до трех запросов в секунду.

> А с циклом всё равно рано или поздно какая нибудь дрянь случится.

Добро пожаловать в мир, где пишут рабочий код.